# square brackets [] when using pointer to list in c++

Tags: c++, list, indexing

I'm taking a look at this code to implement Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm in C++ :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-using-priority_queue-stl/?ref=lbp

At this point in the code I am very confused:

```
Graph::Graph(int V) 
{ 
    this->V = V; 
    adj = new list<iPair> [V]; 
} 
  
void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int w) 
{ 
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w)); 
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w)); 
}
```

adj is a pointer to a list containing pairs of two ints.

```
list< pair<int, int> > *adj;
```

They then use square brackets [] on the adj list. I thought that lists could not be accessed by index. I've tried looking this up everywhere and cannot find anything. The website itself is also not responding. Anyone know what this code is doing?

Comment: There is a difference between `operator new` and `operator new[]`. The former creates *one* object, the latter creates an *array* of objects.

Comment: So they're actually creating an array of lists, and then accessing that array by index?

Comment: If the code you have shown is what they use, then, yes, they are creating an array of lists, where (in your code) `adj` is an array containing `V` objects of `list<iPair>` type.

Comment: @KyleJones _"So they're actually creating an array of lists, and then accessing that array by index?"_ Yes. And the better choice would have been to use a `std::vector<std::list<iPair> adj(N)`.

Comment: @KyleJones Each of the V nodes can be adjacent to a variable number of other nodes, and that is stored in a list. Hence the array of V lists. `adj[n]` likely means "the list of nodes adjacent to node `n`".

Answer (score 0):

> They then use square brackets [] on the adj list

You forgot to show what they do, but I bet that they don't do what you are saying.

I bet that they instead use the subscript operator on the pointer to the list rather than on the pointed list. This is allowed because the list is an element within an array of lists.

P.S. It is not a very high quality tutorial if they use owning bare pointers. Take their code with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, `adj` is an array (a V-length array) of lists.

```cpp
adj = new list<iPair> [V];
```

So brackets are acceptable to access elements of that array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code is not good quality: one should never use `new` directly in application code, containers and smart pointers are enough.

However, the code is valid. `adj` is not a pointer to one list. Note square brackets at the end of the line with `new` in `Graph` constructor. It allocates `V` lists. Then you can refer to these lists as `adj[0]` ... `adj[V-1]`.